# How to query directly the table created by Django for a ManyToMany relation?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have a model `MyModel2` with a `ManyToManyField` related to another model `MyModel1`.

How can I get the pairs `mymodel1.id, mymodel2.id`, as represented in the table Django creates for this relation? Do I have to do a raw SQL query on this table or is it possible through the object managers of this models?

```
class MyModel1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  

class MyModel2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mymodel1 = models.ManyToManyField(MyModel1)
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

This is the many to many field instance:

```
MyModel2.mymodel1
```

This is the intermediary table model:

```
MyModel2.mymodel1.through
```

This is the intermediary model manager:

```
MyModel2.mymodel1.through.objects
```

This returns a queryset for all intermediary models:

```
MyModel2.mymodel1.through.objects.all()
```

[This part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) of django docs talk about `through`. You can make a `through` model yourself, else it is automatically generated.

Comment: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'though'

Comment: You have a typo ;) it's through !

Comment: Clearest explanation of working directly with through tables I've seen - thank you.