# Django get count of object many to many field in a set

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I can't seem to wrap my head around mildly complicated queries in django.

I have a **player** that has **played games**.
each **play** has a many to many field with **players** that **played that game**.

With player1, how do i calculate which opponent he has played the most with django orm?

In SQL I guess this could be counted from the many-to-many table, something like:

```
SELECT player_id, count(*)
FROM play_player
WHERE play_id in (SELECT play_id FROM play_player WHERE player_id = 'player1_id')
```

These are my models:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    """A game to be played and/or owned"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Player(models.Model):
    """Someone who plays games"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    games = models.ManyToManyField(Game)

class Play(models.Model):
    """Players have played a game"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(
        default=timezone.now, help_text='When was the game played?')
    game = models.ForeignKey(
        Game,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        help_text='What game was played?')
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player, help_text='Who was playing?')
    winner = models.ForeignKey(
Player, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='winner')
```

[Gist of models](https://gist.github.com/hvgab/168003a4f073dc736bd9bbe8774b930a)

EDIT:
After I explained in my post that SQL might be something like a query on the many-to-many table, I got some new ideas for google terms.

I'm gonna have another go at it, and reply to my own question if I get it soon.
I was bashing my head against this last night, but a new day might be all that was needed. I need to get a rubber duck I can talk to before I post.

EDIT2:
I posted my own answer below, still happy to take suggestions.

Comment: How many players are involved in a play? Does `Play` mean every time a player plays a play `Play` object is created?

Comment: It's to keep scores of boardgames, so a `Play` should maybe be named `Playthrough`. A `Play` is any amount of `Player`s playing a `Game`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns the values I am after, if someone has a better idea, I'd be glad to accept someone elses answer.

```
def get_most_played_player(self):
    my_plays = self.play_set.all()
    my_plays_ids = [x.id for x in my_plays]
    players_and_count = Play.players.through.objects.filter(
        play_id__in=my_plays_ids).values('player_id').annotate(
            count=Count('player_id')).all()
    for p_c in players_and_count:
        print(t)
        # {'player_id: 1, 'count': 3}
        # etc
    return players_and_count
```

This obviously returns a list of player_ids and count, but add an `order_by` and `first` and we're there.

Comment: Also, thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820579/how-to-query-directly-the-table-created-by-django-for-a-manytomany-relation

Comment: Looks like the right answer! In my opinion you do not need the .all()